# SQL query value not passed to PHP object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an object from a SQL query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM `sales` WHERE `tdate` = CURDATE();");
```

I would think that it should pass ['value] or ['total'] into the object, but it seems to only be returning

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

This makes me think that the query itself is returning NULL, as in there's no results found, however if I run the query in the DB, it returns correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `fetch` result, see below sample code

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM `sales` WHERE `tdate` = CURDATE();"); 
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: have you added `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to fetch query result?